# Parsing floating point values from input results in "exception: no parse"

Tags: haskell, io

I wrote this code :

```
calculIOTest :: IO ()
calculIOTest = do
   putStrLn "Give me two numbers"
   l1 <- getLine
   let x1 = read l1 
   l2 <- getLine
   let x2 = read l2 
   print (x1 + x2)
```

I wanted code that takes two numbers and returns the sum. If I test my function with two integers it works but if I put a float then there is a problem with the error:

```
***Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I would have understood with a string and a number but here I have trouble understanding what is causing the problem.

I tried to review how read works and indeed if I do:

```hs
(read 10000.9) + (read 1115)
```

It gives me the errors:

```
Could not deduce (Fractional String)
        arising from the literal ‘10000.9’
      from the context: (Read a, Num a)
        bound by the inferred type of it :: (Read a, Num a) => a
        at <interactive>:135:1-28
```

and

```
Could not deduce (Num String) arising from the literal ‘1115’
      from the context: (Read a, Num a)
        bound by the inferred type of it :: (Read a, Num a) => a
        at <interactive>:135:1-28
```

I would like to understand why it does not work in my code and where does the error prevent with the read?

Comment: You might also like `readLn`. For a concrete example of the difference, compare the behavior when you enter something that doesn't parse the first time it prompts you: with your code, you must enter a second value before an exception is thrown, while if you used `readLn`, it would throw an exception before waiting for a second value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're adding `x1` and `x2` the compiler can infer that those have to have a `Num` instance and the [default type for `Num a` is `Integer`](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html). So implicitly your code is equivalent to the following:

```hs
calculIOTest :: IO ()
calculIOTest = do
   putStrLn "Give me two numbers"
   l1 <- getLine
   let x1 = (read l1 :: Integer)
   l2 <- getLine
   let x2 = (read l2 :: Integer)
   print (x1 + x2)
```

and obviously you can't parse a float representation as an `Integer`.
To accept `Double`s all you have to do is explicitly annotate that type:

```hs
calculIOTest :: IO ()
calculIOTest = do
   putStrLn "Give me two numbers"
   l1 <- getLine
   let x1 = (read l1 :: Double)
   l2 <- getLine
   let x2 = (read l2 :: Double)
   print (x1 + x2)
```

Your bare reads `(read 10000.9) + (read 1115)` would suffer from the same problem had you included the necessary `"` (`read` takes a `String` not floats or ints)

```hs
read "10000.9" + read "1115"
```

too results in `***Exception: Prelude.read: no parse` and the fix is the same, annotate the type you want.